# Page redirect after time out in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, timer, countdowntimer

I am implementing a timer for a game developed in Rails. When the user clicks on the start game timer will runs and the user will be redirect to another page after X mins.

The problem is when the user is not doing any interactions, the user is redirected to another page after the completion of count down. But when the user is doing interactions like clicking on other links etc countdown timer is not working.

Any hints or ideas how to accomplish the task.

Additionally I would like display a timer in fronted for the user. so can any one give hints about the best approaches to accomplish the task.

I am using following code in the start game page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#start_game').click(function(event){
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      window.location.href= destination_url;
    },600);
  });
});
</script>
```

And the code for start button is

```
<%= link_to "Start Game!", game_root_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", :id=> "start_game" %>
```

I am redirecting to my destination_url if i won't do any interactions after clicking on start button. But in real timer must work irrespective of user interactions once he starts the game.

Comment: Post the code wher eyou detect user interaction plus the part about redirecting the user.

Comment: Check out the link... https://gist.github.com/faffyman/2229725 ... customize and use....

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use JQuery countdown

```
$('#counter').countdown({
    stepTime: 60,
    format: 'hh:mm:ss',
    startTime: "12:32:55",
    digitImages: 6,
    digitWidth: 53,
    digitHeight: 77,
    timerEnd: function() { /* Redirect here */ },
    image: "digits.png"
 });
```

[Demo](http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/